# swal is not rendered in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use the swal for beautiful alert box in my chrome extension. The swal has to be used in background scripts. I have injected the swal code in background scripts property inside manifest.json as well as in web_accessible_resources but alert box of swal is not shown. Why is that so? I used the css in content_scripts.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*", "http://mail.google.com/*"],
    "js": ["extension/js/content.js"],
    "css": ["extension/css/main.css", "extension/css/swal.css"]
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["extension/js/swal.js"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["extension/js/swal.js", "extension/js/eventPage.js", "extension/js/background.js"],
  "persistent": true
},
```

I am using swal inside background.js not in content and popup.

UPDATE

Here is the code for the use of swal in background scripts not in content scripts

```
var selectedTopic = null;
var token = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.message) {
        case 'setTopic':
            window.selectedTopic = request.data;
            break;
        case 'topicCrm':
            savetopic(request.data, sendResponse);
            break;
        default:
            sendResponse({ data: 'Invalid' });
            break;
    }
});

function savetopic(topic) {
    const apiUrl = `${API_BASE}/check_topic/${selectedTopic}`;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Token: ${token}`);
    fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401 || response.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
                sendResponse({ response: 'error' });
            }
            return response.json();
        })
}
```

code for the content scripts. Here i have trimmed the code to not show the position calculation for showing the tooltips

```
// Send a message containing the page details back to the event page

// Add bubble to the top of the page.
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);


var token = null;
function init(event) {
    var topic = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        topic = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        topic = document.selection.createRange().topic;
    } else {
        return topic;
    }
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        { message: 'getToken', key: 'user_token' },
        function(response) {}
    );
    if (topic.length > 0) {
        renderBubble(event, topic);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'setTopic', data: topic }, function(
            response
        ) {});
    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', init);

// Move that bubble to the appropriate location.
function renderBubble(event, selection) {
    bubbleDOM.innerHTML = `<p class="topic" id="topic-crm">${selection}</p>`;
    document.getElementById('topic-crm').addEventListener('click', function() {
        topicCrm(selection);
    });
}

function topicCrm(topic) {
    if (topic) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'topicCrm', data: topic }, function(
            response
        ) { console.log('response', response); // gives undefined });
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the background page is an entirely separate and hidden page, which can't be shown, you need to show the sweet alert in a content script inside the web page (see also: [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)) or show a [notification](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) or open a new small window with the alert via chrome.windows.create.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question with the code. There you see, I am trying to use swal in the background script. I have no idea, how can i use that in the content script instead. Also i have to use the chrome.tabs feature as well.

Comment: Well, you need to read the documentation and find examples of using content scripts. Otherwise you'll need help every little step of the way.

Comment: in the saveTopic inside background script i tried to do the following .then(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 401 || response.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
    console.log('token', sendResponse);
    sendResponse({ data: 'error' });
   }
   return response.json();
  }) so i can listen the response in content script but the response is shown undefined in content script

Comment: changed my code and used sendResponse to send the response back to content script but i am getting undefined. Why is that so?